# Converter diagrama de sequencia para Java

Tags: java, diagrama

Estou resolvendo exercícios sobre modelagem, e em um exercício é dado um diagrama de sequencia, e eu gostaria de converter esse diagrama para código Java, considerando que a execução inicia de um método X da classe A, para que eu consiga entender melhor o que está acontecendo.
O diagrama foi criado usando o Astah

[image: Diagrama]

Comment: Sua pergunta tá incompleta.. O diagrama mostrado foi desenhado em algum software? Se sim, qual?

Comment: Fiz algumas correções na pergunta

Comment: Veja no menu principal: [Tool] - [Java] - [Export Java]

Answer (score 0):

Monte o diagrama de classe contendo as classes que compõe o problema e dele gere o código java (usando o tools->java no astah). Apenas o diagrama de sequência dado assim fica incompleto.